# how to use ruby code inside javascript code in haml?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, haml

I'm developing my application on rails 5 using haml, and I need to do a "each" inside the javascript code to show the data of a stored procedure so that a graph can be displayed.
The problem is that I can't render the data inside javascript. Without haml it would be something like this:

```
<script>
var config = {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [
              <% @result.to_a.each do |foo| %>
                "<%= foo["balance"] %>"
                <%= "," unless foo == @result.to_a.last %>
              <% end %>
            ], ...
</script>
```

this is my _partial.html.haml

```
%canvas{id: 'myChart', width: '400', height: '130'}

:javascript



    var config = {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [
                  #{@result.to_a.each do |foo| 
                    "#{foo["balance"]}"#{","}
                  end}
                ],
                backgroundColor: [
                  "#F7464A",
                  "#46BFBD",
                  "#FDB45C",
                  "#949FB1",
                  "#4D5360",
                ],
                label: 'Dataset 1'
            }],
            labels: [
              "Red",
              "Green",
              "Yellow",
              "Grey",
              "Dark Grey"
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Chart.js Doughnut Chart'
            },
            animation: {
                animateScale: true,
                animateRotate: true
            }
        }
    };

    window.pPercentage = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), config);
```

it doesn't show me an error in the console, it just doesn't show me the graph

Comment: Your question is tagged with rails 4 and rails 5, which one are you using?

Comment: @SuperStormer rails 5